# Addressing an index in array in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua, love2d, addressing

I am trying to write a simple game using **Love 2d** engine. It uses **lua** as the scripting language. I have some problems with arrays and can't find any solution. Here is my issue:

```
for i = 1, 10 do 
    objects.asteroids = {} 
    objects.asteroids[i] = {} 
    objects.asteroids[i].body = love.physics.newBody(world, 650/2, 650/2, "dynamic")
    objects.asteroids[i].size = 3 
    objects.asteroids[i].angle = math.random(6) 
end
```

In the same function I am trying to do a following operation:

```
for i = 1, 10 do 
    objects.asteroids[i].size = 2 
end
```

And I get this error when trying to run my game:

> Error 
>   main.lua:48: attempt to index a nil value

Where line 48 refers to this line of code:

```
objects.asteroids[i].size = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `objects.asteroids` on each loop iteration.

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  objects.asteroids = {} -- <== Here.
  objects.asteroids[i] = {}
```

What this means is that the asteroid objects that you're trying to add end up being erased on the next step of the loop, since `object.asteroids` is set to a new `{}` table and the old one becomes inaccessible thereafter.

You might want to rearrange it like so:

```
objects.asteroids = {}

for i = 1, 10 do
  objects.asteroids[i] = {}
  -- ...
```

Comment: Thanks, now it seems so trivial :).